# Unix Source command equivalent in Python

Tags: python

In Unix we have a **SOURCE** command that can load a text file inside the shell script and all those parameters inside the text file is available as variables inside the script. Do we have an equivalent to that in python ? I need to load a properties file from the edge node to the .py script and based on the values take decisions inside the .py script.

```
Sample job.properties file in edge node is below.
databaseName=employee
hdfspath=/tenancy/ida/data
....
```

I need to load this job.properties file inside the .py script so that i need not pass these as command line arguments.  Kindly advise

Comment: Make use of the `import` mechanism, I'd have thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact customize the [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) mechanism for such purposes. However, let me provide a quick hack instead:

```
def source(filename):
    variables = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                name, value = line.strip().split('=')
            except:
                continue
            variables[name] = value
    return variables

variables = source('job.properties')
print(variables)
```

The function `source` iterates over the lines in the supplied file and store the assignments in the `dict`ionary `variables`. In case of lines not containing assignment, the `try`/`except` will simply skip it.

To emulate the behavior of shell sourcing further, you might add

```
globals().update(variables)
```

if working at the module (non-function) level, which will make `databaseName` and `hdfspath` available as Python variables.

Note that all "sourced" variables will be `str`s, even for lines such as `my_int=42` in the sourced file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'exec' to achieve something similar to 'source'. It is not a nice thing to do.

It would look like:

```
with open("variables.py") as fi:
    exec(fi.read())
```

Easiest option is to use configparser module for ini files.
If that is not desirable, try modules like yaml or json.